# Linux command line error message: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns

I'm getting error message "Temporary failure in name resolution" when trying to ping a domain name such as a website.  When I ping a discrete IP address then ping works normally.

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

This problem only happens when trying to ping a domain instead of an IP, so this seems to be a DNS problem.

My `/etc/resolve.conf` specifies DNS server 127.0.0.57. After I added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and restarted the service that seemed to fix the problem. However this may be only short term, it may break again, So I need a long term solution.
If anyone has a solution to this issue, it could be awesome.

Comment: 1) Disable the systemd-resolved service. `sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service`
2) Stop the Service `sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service`
3) Remove the Configuration file manually `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf`
4) Now, Create the file again `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`
5) Enter this Lines and save it `nameserver 8.8.8.8`
6) Enable the Service `sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service`
7) Start the Service back `sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved.service`

[Got this solution from here](https://letsfoss.com/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution)

Comment: @MCNaveen First I advice to backup `/etc/resolv.conf` in case things does not go well

Comment: I'm surprised why there are many lines of code when changing the `/etc/resolv.conf` file to 8.8.8.8 literally fixed the problem for me. No need to disable a service, etc.

Comment: @DaWe Yes. Only need to change DNS server.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

I've faced the exactly same problem but I've fixed it with another approache.

Using Ubuntu 18.04, first disable `systemd-resolved` service.

`sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service`

Stop the service

`sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service`

Then, remove the link to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` in `/etc/resolv.conf`

`sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf`

Add a manually created `resolv.conf` in `/etc/`

`sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf`

Add your prefered DNS server there

`nameserver 208.67.222.222`

I've tested this with success.

Comment: According to the archlinux wiki on [Systemd-resolved](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved), it looks as if it is the right way to do it (well, at least one of the right ways :) ).

Comment: Well, this works....until i reboot, then it changes back, so I have to run these commands everytime i boot

Comment: is it just me, or does systemd create unnecessary problems?

Comment: for me, it worked modifying indirectly resolv.conf via head. see pchelp.ricmedia.com/set-custom-dns-servers-linux-network-manager-resolv-conf/ @Mike1982

Comment: Is there any additional step to make this more permanent? As others stated, a reboot brings this issue back and the steps above have to be taken again. I would have expected that systemd disabling the service at startup would have been enough

Comment: I'm having the same issue and your solution didn't work for me.

Comment: @TitoValentin Have you tried making a bash script and call it from crontabs? maybe not the best solution but it might work.

Comment: this tip saved my day. I'm using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: this messed up my internet connection

Comment: If this gets reverted after a reboot then update or create /etc/wsl.conf, adding: 
[network]
generateResolvConf = false

Comment: ANy permanent solution? Need to do this everytime after system restart.

Comment: Does it affect the site I ran with the `nginx ` and `gunicorn`?

Comment: @Varun check the ricmedia link from Ferroao above, it worked for me

Comment: @Mike1982 you need to make it a demon, and  enable the sytemd after doing above mentioned things.

Comment: To make it permanent you have to create a directory

```sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/ ```

Create a file

```sudo vim /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf```

with following content:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
```

Then restart service: ```systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service```

Comment: Am I the only one who find astonishing that one of the oldest services since the creation of Internet is so buggy on Linux?

Comment: What should I do? I am facing the same erro on kali linux

Answer (score 6):

If you get the IP address from a DHCP server, you can also set the server to send a DNS server. Or add the `nameserver 8.8.8.8` into /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base file. The information in this file is included in the resolver configuration file even when no interfaces are configured.